# Wrap parameters in AngularJS service for update API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, api, service

I'm trying to do update with AngularJS and API

Service: expense.js

```
angular
  .module('timeTrackerApp.services',[])
  .service('Expense', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/expenses/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
      'update': {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      'destroy': {
        method: 'DELETE'
      }
    })
  }])
```

Controller: expenses_controller.rb

```
def permitted_params
   params.require(:expense).permit(:name, :price)
end
```

So expected JSON format is { expense: { name: "value", price: value } }

but i'm getting  { name: "value", price: value }

So can anyone help me wrap this into root node ( expense ) ?

Comment: you should tag with ruby.

Comment: is `Expense` a model?

Comment: Yes, do you need more info?

Comment: `wrap_parameters` in Rails automatically namespaces params, so I guess `name` and `price` are not attributes of the model

Comment: They are, i need to send json in different format, i need to include root node, not just params

Comment: yeah I understood, but it should be automatical, as I told you `wrap_parameters` does it by default if the controller name matches a model name

Comment: ok, is there a way to wrap it somehow in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails automatically does wrap parameters when controller name matches a model name. [Check doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

If ever it fails, you can do it manually, in your controller:

```
 wrap_parameters :expense, include: [:name, :price]
```

so if you receive:

```
 { name: 'name', price: 'price' }
```

Controller will give you:

```
 { name: 'name', price: 'price', expense: { name: 'name', price: 'price' } }
```

So do this server side since its neat and simple.